# Android: Set Margin for Edit Text in AlertDialog Box

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-alertdialog, android-5.1.1-lollipop

I am trying to create an **Alert Dialog** box like **Lollipop**, everything is going fine but I am stuck in one section the case of **EditText**

I want an **EditText** with underline and **margin left and right** with 20dp.For underline I tried **setBackground()** , and its working fine.

But there is a problem that **setBackground()** will not work **API** Level below 16.

For setMargin I tried

```
 final EditText input = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    lp.setMargins(30,0,30,0);
    input.setLayoutParams(lp);
    input.setGravity(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_GRAVITY);
    input.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.edit_text_line)); 
    builder.setView(input);
```

But Edit Text using full parent width.

**Full Code**

```
  AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Message");
    builder.setMessage("Do you want to\n"+""+"exit from app");

    final EditText input = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    lp.setMargins(30,0,30,0);
    input.setLayoutParams(lp);
    input.setGravity(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_GRAVITY);
    input.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.edit_text_line)); //call reequires api 16 and above
    builder.setView(input);

    builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You exit from app " + input.getText().toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });

    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
    Button nbutton = alert.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE);
    nbutton.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#7e7e7e"));
    Button pbutton = alert.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
    pbutton.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#109c8f"));
```

Is there any way to set the **background** for the **EditText** that work below API 16 and **setMargin** left and right for the **EditText**.

Comment: One workaround for margin thing can be add a linear layout and set left and right padding to this layout. put your edittext inside this linearlayout instead of putting it directly inside the dialog.

Comment: try using ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams  ..!!!

Comment: @Binil S see my answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Margins on root view won't work. Try adding padding to parent layout as told in other answers.

But rather than creating dialog layout in java, I would advice you to inflate an xml and use [AppCompatEditText](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/AppCompatEditText.html) if you want to use line background

Here's a sample code for you

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setTitle("Message");
// Why are you setting message here when you are inflating custom view?
// You need to add another TextView in xml if you want to set message here
// Otherwise the message will not be shown
// builder.setMessage("Do you want to\n"+""+"exit from app");
View view = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.dialog_layout, null);
final AppCompatEditText input = (AppCompatEditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText);
builder.setView(view);
builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        dialog.cancel();
    }
});

builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You exit from app " + input.getText().toString(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
});

AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
alert.show();
```

Lastly you cannot get buttons instantly after creating dialog. You need to do this in [OnShowListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/DialogInterface.OnShowListener.html) if you want to customize button text colors. Or use `android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog` for newer Dialog designs.

```
Button nbutton = alert.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE);
// will be null
// nbutton.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#7e7e7e"));
Button pbutton = alert.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
// will be null
// pbutton.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#109c8f"));
```

**dialog_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this code it work for me.

```
     final EditText input = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
     input.setSingleLine();
     FrameLayout container = new FrameLayout(thisActivity);
     FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new  FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

     params.topMargin = convertDpToPx(30);
     params.bottomMargin = convertDpToPx(30);

     input.setLayoutParams(params);
     container.addView(input);
```

Comment: When using inside an AlertDialog, don't forget to add the container as VIEW for the alertDialog :- alertDialog.setView(container);

Answer (score 0):

**May this Helps**

this work for me...

by setting `RelativeLayout` As Root Of `EditText` becouse **margins on root view won't work.**

```
public void ShowDialog() {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        alertDialog.setTitle("App Name");
        alertDialog.setMessage("Message");
        final EditText input = new EditText(getContext());
        input.setHint("Hint Text");
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        lp.setMargins(36,36,36,36);
        input.setLayoutParams(lp);
        RelativeLayout container = new RelativeLayout(getContext());
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlParams=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        container.setLayoutParams(rlParams);
        container.addView(input);
        //now set view to dialog
        alertDialog.setView(container);
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Ohk", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                if (input.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                    input.setText("No Valid");
                    return;
                }
            }
        });
        alertDialog.show();
    }
```